# slds-grid question

Tags: slds, slds-grid

Would it be possible to create an slds-grid like below?

[image]

Comment: On a mobile device the grid would normally collapse into a stack. Do you want the number 3 cell to be after number 2 or is it supposed to be after number 7?

Comment: It would go after #2

Comment: I think you would need to use nested grids. The outer would have two columns (one row), with the first cell containing the second grid with two columns and 3 rows. Still, that means 3 would appear below all the rest if the layout is reflowed...

Comment: I think it's doable, but it's not exactly pretty. With nested grids you can get the large view port as you've drawn, but I don't think you can then collapse them where #2 is still followed by #3. You could however add #3 again after #2 (and within the nested grid) and hide/show them depending on the view port https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/visibility/#Responsive